# Migrations created in a different (discarded) branch are showing up in master

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I was trying out Passport to learn about it, but wasn't sure I wanted to use it in my project, so I created a new branch called Passport and messed around in there. Passport ended up creating some migrations, which I had run and created the necessary tables.

Eventually I decided, that I didn't want to move forward with it, and used 'git reset --hard' to destroy all changes made. I checked out my master branch again, and got rid of the Passport branch entirely.

I manually deleted any files that were created by Passport which were in .gitignore folders, of this I'm sure. My database migrations folder only has the migrations which I need. So I decided to do a fresh setup of my database once again just to make sure all the junk I put in there during my experiment was cleaned out. I did:

```
php artisan migrate:reset  
composer dump-autoload  
php artisan migrate
```

But for some strange reason, I still get the migrations from the Passport branch and those tables get created as well. I triple checked the migrations folder and none of those migration files are there. I did php artisan migrate:status and can see all those migrations showing up there. I checked the migrations table in the database and it is empty (after running migrate:reset).

Everywhere I've researched, it simply says "Rollback the migration, delete the migration file, run composer dump-autoload to ensure that the migration directory is re-scanned, and then carry on running migrations like you always do".

In a couple of places it also says to run 'php artisan optimize' after dump-autoload, but that command has been removed since 5.4 (https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/17003)

Would love some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out guys. Basically I needed to run 'composer install' which removed all the extra stuff that had been brought in when I installed Passport.

After doing that, and doing composer dump-autoload, and then doing a fresh migration, it worked.